# React: How do you intentionally add an onclick property with a string value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

I need to specifically use the regular html `onclick` attribute and not React's `onClick` property because I want to add Google Analytics to [track outbound links](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en).

If I use the `onClick` property with a function as the property, `ga` will not be defined, so if I can just make the value a string, it shouldn't throw any errors.

Comment: Have you tried the [react-ga](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) library and their [`outboundLink` function](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga#reactgaoutboundlinkargs-hitcallback) or [`OutboundLink` component](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga#outboundlink-component)?

Comment: Try calling it from `window.ga`.